# Does holding certain objects in your hand change your movement speed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering, are there any movement speed differences if you hold specific objects in your hand?

I'm interested even in a small movement speed difference, like, in decimals.

Comment: As an aside, I do believe there are mods that add the equivalent of rocket boots, as well as mods that let you adjust your walking speed, although the former mods are usually either SMP only, or not usable in SMP, but the latter *is* generally useable in SMP, but some PvP servers might make attempts at limiting its use.

Comment: Well, yes, with mods you can do plainly everything, I was more interested in native movespeed, but huh, I guess I'll have to do with no movespeed alterations.

Comment: Maybe you should craft a knife? ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are no objects or items that affect your movement speed while *held*, but there are certain objects that will affect your movement speed when *used*:

- When thrown, [ender pearls](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Pearl) will teleport you to the location at which they land (1.9-pre2+)
- You can craft [potions of swiftness](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Brewing#Awkward_Base) that will increase your speed for a short period of time (1.9-pre3+)

There are also environmental effects and actions that modify your movement speed:

- Walking on [soul sand](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Soul_Sand)
- Using a [Minecart](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecart)
- Swimming in [water](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Water)
- [Sneaking](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sneaking)
- [Sprinting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sprinting)
- Riding in a [boat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Boat)
- [Explosions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/TNT#Explosion_Properties) and [TNT Cannons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/TNT_Cannons) (assuming you live)
- Walking through [cobwebs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cobweb)
- Walking across [ice](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ice)

Comment: But.. But.. Everyone walks faster with a knife?

Comment: @nightcracker: While that *is* true, there are no knives in Minecraft.

Comment: If you're counting sneaking, you should edit in sprinting as well.

Answer (score 0):

Holding items won't affect your speed, but walking on some items, like water, soul sand, and lava will.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? while brief, its totally correct!

Comment: Because it doesn't add anything over the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.6.4, attribute modifiers have been added, which are of much use to custom map makers.  If you hold an item with an attribute modifier for speed on it, it will change your movement speed, though this is only in maps as attribute modifiers for speed are impossible to obtain in vanilla minecraft.